# default snapshot location for velero

Tags: azure, kubernetes, velero

I want to use velero with my azure Kubernetes cluster to backup cluster data and persistent volumes.

Like doc says I have annotated the pods and even backup job shows 4 snapshots successful.

I managed to take the backup for the cluster and I can see it in my azure storage account. the problem is I see only gz files and one json file in my storage accounts velero designated container. Shouldn't I see a file equivalent to my PVs ?(which is about 10GB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in fact is the correct setup. You should see only json files and gziped files in the backup folder within valero container.

These files have pointers to actual snapshots in azure. look for the snapshots within resource group you specified during backup. There should be snapshots corresponding to PVC size.

Comment: This is correct. To complement: Velero triggers a snapshot via the provider api/sdk, it does not actually get a copy of the snapshot, only a pointer to it.